# Insertion Array Sorting Method

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

I am currently a student working on an insertion sort method.
Below is the code:

```
//Insertion Sorting of an Integer array
void InsertionSort(int insertVals[]){


    //Systematic processing of the Array
    for(int i = 0; i < INITSIZE - 1; i++){
        //Value to check
        int temp = insertVals[i];

        //Index placeholder for the insterion sort
        int k;

        //Shifts the int array
        for(k = i; k > 0 && insertVals[k-1] > temp; k--){
            insertVals[k] = insertVals[k-1];
        }

        //Inserts the checked value back into the array
        insertVals[k] = temp;   

    }
}
```

In my tests, I have given it the array from left to right:

```
307 249  73 158 430 272  44 378 423 209 
440 165 492  42 487   3 327 229 340 112 
303 169 209 157  60 433  99 278 316 335 
 97 326  12 267 310 133 479 149  79 321 
467 172 393 336 485 245 228  91 194 357 
  1 153 208 444 168 490 124 196  30 403 
222 166  49  24 301 353 477 408 228 433 
298 481 135  13 365 314  63  36 425 169 
115  94 129   1  17 195 105 404 451 298 
188 123   5 382 252  66 216 337 438 144
```

The method produces from left to right:

```
314  63 314  63  36 425  36 169 425 169 
115 115  94 129  94 129   1  17 195 105 
404 451 298 188 123   5 382 252  66 216 
337 438 144   1  17 195 105 404 451 298 
188 123   5 382 252  66 216 337 438 144 
228 229 245 249 252 267 272 278 298 298 
301 303 307 310 314 316 321 326 327 335 
336 337 340 353 357 365 378 382 393 403 
404 408 423 425 430 433 433 438 440 444 
451 467 477 479 481 485 487 490 492 144
```

What am I incorrectly coding?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
//In main...
Printing(insertionSortValues, "Insertion Sorted Array");

//Function for Print
void Printing(int vals[], string s){
    cout << s << ":" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < INITSIZE; i++){
        if(i % 10 == 0){
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << setw(3) << vals[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Try changing your first `for` loop to begin at `int i=1`... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: It still produces the same sort. I think I was doing things similar to the wiki page.

Comment: Yeah, your algorithm looks correct (other than that) when comparing to the wikipedia link. Could it be just how you are printing out the sorted array? Maybe post that code as well.

Comment: I have just made the edit.

Comment: @NicholasHayden Instead of sorting so many numbers, try your code with 3, 4, or 5 numbers.  If you can't sort a small list, it doesn't make sense to inundate yourself in trying to figure out where it goes wrong with 100 numbers.

Comment: @NicholasHayden For example, make `INITSIZE` 5.  Try to sort this: `314,  63, 314,  63,  36`  You will see your code fails on just these 5 numbers.  So right away you know that something is fundamentally wrong since a tiny list of numbers fails to sort correctly.

Comment: I just tried with 5 numbers, and found the error! Ill post the solution.

Comment: Also, if INTSIZE is the size of your array, you should write `for(int i = 0; i < INITSIZE; i++)` instead of `INITSIZE - 1`, otherwise your last element won't be sorted. Other than that, the code you provided works for me, so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was solved through @PaulMcKenzie.
The line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < INITSIZE - 1; i++){
```

needed to become:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= INITSIZE - 1; i++){
```

---

Below is the corrected function.

```
//Insertion Sorting of an Integer array
void InsertionSort(int insertVals[]){


    //Systematic processing of the Array
    for(int i = 0; i <= INITSIZE - 1; i++){
        //Value to check
        int temp = insertVals[i];

        //Index placeholder for the insterion sort
        int k;

        //Shifts the int array
        for(k = i; k > 0 && insertVals[k-1] > temp; k--){
            insertVals[k] = insertVals[k-1];
        }

        //Inserts the checked value back into the array
        insertVals[k] = temp;   

    }
}
```